# Problem with \include and \chapter

Tags: errors

I am including the chapters of my thesis with the `\include` command. The chapters start with `\chapter`. This worked until last week, but suddenly TeXStudio won't compile. I get an `! extra \else` error.
If I change `\include` to `\input` or if I comment `\chapter`, it works.

I assume the error comes from somewhere inside my header. The header is part of my faculty template, they told me to use it. Any ideas?

```
\input{./Header}


\begin{document}
    
    \input{./pagestyle}

    \tableofcontents
    
    \include{./chapter}


\end{document}
```

The chapter looks like this:

```
\chapter{Konzeption und Umsetzung}


\section{Antriebsstrang}

\subsection{Komponenten}
...
```

Pagestyle:

```
\automark{chapter}                                  
        \pagestyle{useheadings}                             
        \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}      
        \setlength{\headheight}{1 cm}
        \addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\linespread{0.5}\selectfont}   
        \ohead{\headmark}
```

The header:

```
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
%% Definition der Dokumentenklassen %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 

\documentclass[
    listof=numbered,                                %   Listen nummeriert einfügen
    listof=flat,                                    %   Abstand in Verzeichnissen anpassen
    pdftex,                                         %   PDFTex verwenden
    a4paper,                                        %   A4 Papier
    oneside,                                        %   Zweiseitig
    %BCOR1cm,                                       %   Randzugabe bei Duplex
    listof=totoc,                                   %   Tabellen und Abbildungsverzeichnis nicht nummeriert
    bibliography=totoc,                             %   Literaturverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
    headsepline,                                    %   Linie nach Kopfzeile
    %footsepline,                                   %   Linie vor Fusszeile
    11pt,                                           %   Schriftgröße
    %smallheadings                                  %
    ngerman,                                        %   Neue deutsche Rechtschreibung
    fleqn,                                          %   Formeln linksbündig statt zentriert
    %draft,                                         %   Schnelles Renderung
]{scrreprt}                                         %   Wissenschaftlicher Report. Alternativ {scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrpage2}                               %   Seitenlayout mit KOMA-Script
\usepackage{scrhack}                                %   Gegen die Fehlermeldung "\float@addtolists detected!(scrreprt)..."


% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
%% Formatierungs und Layoutoptionen %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 

%% Schriften setzen auf Serifenlos
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}           %   Standardschrift: serifenlos
\usepackage{cmbright}                               %   Schriftart ersteinmal alles auf serifenlos nach cmbright inkl. Mathefonts
\usepackage{helvet}                                 %   Schriftart dann auf serifenlos nach Helevetica (Mathefonts sind nicht enthalten)

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}                         %   Kapitelnummerierung mit fünf Ebenen ermöglichen
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}                            %   Eintrag ins Inhaltsverzeichnis bis Ebene 3

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}                         %   Erstzeileneinzug bei neuem Absatz verhindern
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}                           %   Abstand zwischen Absätzen einstellen 
\setcapindent{1em}                                  %   Abstand zwischen Absätzen einstellen
%\linespread{1.15}                                  %   Zeilenabstand einstellen

\usepackage{chngcntr}                               %   Fußnoten im gesamten Text durchgehend nummerieren (sonst Neubeginn nach Kapitelwechsel)
\counterwithout*{footnote}{chapter}                 %   Fußnoten im gesamten Text durchgehend nummerieren

\newcounter{mpglobal}                               %   Um Fußnoten in Minipages fortlaufend zu nummerieren
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}  %   Arabische Zahlen in Minipage Fußnoten

\clubpenalty = 10000                                %   Schliesst Schusterjungen aus
\widowpenalty = 10000                               %   Schliesst Hurenkinder aus

%% Deutsche Anpassungen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                         %   Ermöglicht deutsche Silbentrennung und direkte Eingabe von Umlauten
\addto\captionsngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{Abbildung}                 %
  \renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabelle}                %
  \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis} %
}
\usepackage[]{inputenc}                     %   Teilt LaTeX die Texcodierung mit. Bei Windowssystemen: ansinew, latin1
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}          %   Gegen Fehler "'babel' detected but 'csquotes' missing." bei Verwendung von BibLaTeX
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                            %   Ermöglicht die Silbentrennung von Wörtern mit Umlauten
\usepackage{eurosym}                                %   Euro darstellen

%% Packages für Formeln %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{amsmath}                                %   Mathematikpaket
\usepackage{amstext}                                %   Text in Formeln: This style file implements the AMS-TEX macro \text
\usepackage{amsthm}                                 %   Verbesserte Theorem Darstellung: \newtheorem{lem}{Lemma} zur Def.; \begin{lem} Text text ... \end{lem} zum Einsatz
\usepackage{amsfonts}                               %   Schriften für AMSMath
\usepackage{dsfont}                                 %   mathds alternativ zu mathbb für richtige Darstellen Natürlicher Zahlen: \mathds{N} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}                               %   Support for using RSFS fonts in maths; Provides a \mathscr command, rather than overwriting the standard \mathcal command
\usepackage{amssymb}                                %   Advanced Mathematical Symbols
\usepackage{upgreek}                                %   Non Italic Greek Characters
%\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}                    %   Erweiterung des mathbb für Griechisch etc.
\usepackage{nicefrac}                               %   Typeset in-line fractions in a "nice" way:  \nicefrac
\usepackage{amsxtra}                                %   Weitere Extrasymbole
%\usepackage{icomma}                                %   defining an ?intelligent? comma, which ?recognizes?, whether it is used as a decimal separator or as a punctuation character.
                                                    %   After loading of the package, the comma will be typeset as a punctuation character, if the next input character is a space; otherwise the comma is treated as a decimal separator. Thus, a decimal number is to be entered as, for instance: 1,234 whereas the mathematical expression(x,y) is to be written with a space after the comma: (x, y)


%% Packages für Einheiten %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\usepackage{siunitx}                               %   Alternative Darstellung von Einheiten
%\usepackage{fancyunits}                            %   Alternative Darstellung von Einheiten
%%\usepackage{gensymb}                              %   The gensymbpackage provides a number of ?generic? macros, which produce the same output in text and math mode: #
                                                    %   \degree \celsius \perthousand \ohm \micro
\usepackage{units}
%\usepackage{nicefrac}
%%\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{unitsdef}
\newunit{\kgmm}{\kg\unitsep\squaremeter}
\newunit{\newtonmeter}{\newton\meter}
\newunit{\degreepersecond}{\per{\degree}{\second}}
\newunit{\radpersecond}{\per{\radian}{\second}}
\newunit{\radpersquaresecond}{\per{\radian}{\squaresecond}}
\newunit{\meterpersecond}{\per{\meter}{\second}}
\newunit{\kmperhour}{\per{\kilometer}{\hour}}
\newunit{\mph}{mph}
\newunit{\inch}{in}
\newunit{\squaresecond}{\second\unitsuperscript{2}}
\newunit{\meterpersquaresecond}{\per{\meter}{\squaresecond}}
\newunit{\g}{g}
\newunit{\barSI}{bar}

%% Zusatzpakete
\usepackage[space]{grffile}                         %   Grafiken mit Leerzeichen im Namen einfügen
\usepackage{blindtext}                              %   Blindtext einfügen: http://texblog.org/2011/02/26/generating-dummy-textblindtext-with-latex-for-testing/
                                                    %   \blindtext, \Blindtext for paragraph(s) of text.
                                                    %   \blinddocument, \Blinddocument for a small/large document.
                                                    %   
                                                    %   In an arbitrary number of repetitions, e.g. \blindtext[5].
                                                    %   
                                                    %   Furthermore, \blindlist{env}[x] creates a list with ?x? being the number of items generated. The environment can be set to itemize, enumerate or description.
                                                    %   
                                                    %   A more direct way to generate lists is by using the commands: c, \blindenumerate, \blinddescription and their extended versions with capital letters are available. Similarly, the number of items is defined through the optional argument, e.g. \blindenumerate[10].
                                                    %   
                                                    %   If you want math within the text, use \blindmathtrue and \blindmathfalse respectively.
                                                    %   
                                                    %   It is also possible to generate text with math including formulas, using \blindmathpaper.
\usepackage{lipsum}                                 %   Lorem Ipsum Blindtext
\usepackage{setspace}                               %   Zeilenabstand setzen mit \onehalfspacing,...
\usepackage{color}                                  %   Farben ermöglichen
\usepackage{lscape}                                 %   Ermöglicht Drehen einzelner Seiten
\usepackage{rotating}                               %   Ermöglicht das drehen von bildern (sidewaysfigure) und Text in Tabellen
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}                     %   Mehr Farben
\usepackage{threeparttable}                         %   Für Fußnoten in Tabellen
\usepackage{multicol}                               %   Mehrspaltige Listen
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}                 %   Automatisches Abkürzungsverzeichnis

%% Bilder %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{graphicx}                               %   Grafiken einbinden
\usepackage{float}                                  %   Bilder WIRKLICH an der Stelle einsetzen, mit Parameter [H]
\usepackage{capt-of}                                %   Beschriftung nicht gleitender Bilder
\usepackage[% 
format=hang,% Bereich unter Abbildung xx bleibt frei 
indention = 0pt, % Einzug von 0 pt 
justification=RaggedRight, % Beschriftung linksbündig 
font={footnotesize, sf}, %Schriftart und -größe wie im Fließtext, it = kursiv, Text 
labelfont={normalfont, sf}, %%Schriftart und -größe wie im Fließtext, it = kursiv, bf = fett, Bezeichner 
margin=0.05\textwidth,
singlelinecheck=true,
%nooneline % Überprüfung auf Einzellinien aus 
skip= 5pt, %Abstand zwischen Bild und Beschriftung 
]{caption} %Zum Formatieren von Bildbeschriftungen. Caption in longtable nicht in anderer Textgröße (Bei \small vor longtable)
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}                       %   LaTeX commands can be placed on the graphic at defined positions; a grid for orientation is available.
%\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}                       %   PDF Dateien einfügen ermöglichen; Funktioniert nicht mehr zusammen mit graphicx
\usepackage{subfigure}                              %   enable pictures side-by-side

%% Tabellen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{array,ragged2e}                     %   Erweitert Tabelleneigenschaften (Blocksatz ausschalten)
\usepackage{longtable}                              %   Für Tabellen, die eine Seite überschreiten
%\captionsetup[longtable]{justification=raggedright,position=bottom} % Caption für longtable definieren
\usepackage{multirow}                               %   Tabellen mit mehrzeiligen Zellen
\usepackage{tabularx}                               %   Widths of certain columns are calculated so that the table is is a specied width: \begin{tabularx}{hwidthi}{hpreamblei}
\usepackage{tabulary}                               %   Tabellen fügt Blocksatz in Tabellenspalten hinzu: LCRJ statt nur LCR als Ausrichtungsdefinitionen
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{ltxtable}                               %   LongtableX (Mehrseitige tabellen mit X) / merged tabularx/longtable package, \LTXtable{<width>}{<file name>}
                                                    %   The \multicolumn command is suppressed in environments included in this way.
\usepackage{colortbl}                               %   Farben in Tabellen: \columncolor[ hcolor model i ]{hcolour i}[hleft overhang i ][hright overhangi]
%\captionsetup[table]{position=top,aboveskip=3pt}   %   Vertikale Abstände für TabellenÜBERschriften einrichten

%\renewcommand*{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}          %   Vertically centers entries of a tabularx-table

\usepackage{paralist}                               %   Zusätzliche Listenumgebungen: \begin{enumerate}[1)]\item Eins\item Zwei\item drei\end{enumerate}
                                                    %   Die jeweiligen compact Varianten unterdrücken die standardmäßigen Durchschüsse zwischen den Umgebungen und dem übrigen Text, sowie zwischen den einzelnen Aufzählungspunkten. Die aspara Varianten setzten jeden Listenpunkt als einzelnen Absatz. Die inpara Varianten setzen die Listenpunkte fortlaufend als einen Absatz. [compactenum, compactitem, compactdesc], entsprechend für aspara und inpara
\usepackage{booktabs}                               %   Setzen von qualitativ hochwertigen horizontalen Strichen (engl. rules) in Tabellen.
                                                    %   Im Wesentlichen bietet booktabs 3 Befehle an, um horizontale Rules zu setzen. Dabei ist \toprule[<breite>] der Befehl für einen die Tabelle oben abschließenden Strich und \midrule[<breite>] für einen Strich innerhalb der Tabelle. \cmidrule[<breite>](trim){a-b} ist der Befehl für einen Strich innerhalb der Tabelle von Spalte a bis b und \bottomrule ist der Befehl für einen die Tabelle abschließenden Strich. 
\usepackage{hhline}                                 %   cline auch bei gefärbten Reihen. Doppelte REcieh mit = statt - ; Doku siehe: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hhline
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}                         %   Erlaubt \underline
\usepackage[numbered]{mcode} %framed                %   Erlaubt es, farbig richtig codierten MatLab Code einzufügen (auch mit Rahmen)#
%\usepackage{verbatim}                              %   Erweiterung zum Quellcode einbinden (Latex Code wird nciht interpretiert)
%\usepackage{listings}                              %   Direktes einbinden von Quellcode als Listings (statt mcode oder verbatim)
\usepackage{url}                                    %   Darstellung von Weblinks mit dem \url{http://www.seite.de} Parameter
\urlstyle{same}                                     %   Url in gleicher Schrifart, statt blau


%% Packages für PDF %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hyperref} 
%% PDF Dokuinfo 
 \hypersetup{ 
    pdftitle={Semesterarbeit}, 
    pdfauthor={\textcopyright\ Lukas Wheldon}, 
    pdfsubject = {Entwicklung und Aufbau eines elektrischen Rennsportmotorrades}, 
    pdfcreator = {pdfLaTeX}, 
    pdfkeywords = {}, 
    plainpages=false, 
    pdfstartview=Fit, 
    colorlinks=true, 
    linkcolor=black,
    breaklinks=true,
    citecolor=black,
    pdftoolbar=true,
    bookmarksnumbered,
    bookmarksopenlevel=2,
    bookmarksopen=true, 
    pdfstartpage=1,
    % pdfpagemode=FullScreen
    % pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight,
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines, %UseOutlines stellt Bookmarks dar, UseNone schaltet die Anzeige dieser ab
    hypertexnames=false,
    urlcolor = black,
  }


%% durchgängiges Hoch-Tiefstellen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Für das Hochstellen von Zeichen ohne Einschaltung des Mathematikmodus
%bietet LaTeX die Anweisung \textsuperscript an.
%Mit den folgenden Definitionen, die analog der Definiton von
%\textsuperscript sind, erhält man eine entsprechende Anweisung
%\textsubscript zum Tiefstellen von Zeichen ohne den Mathemodus zu verwenden
% Bsp. CO\textsubscript{2} für Darstellung von Kohlendioxid

 \makeatletter   
    \DeclareRobustCommand*\textsubscript[1]{% 
      \@textsubscript{\selectfont#1}} 
    \def\@textsubscript#1{% 
      {\m@th\ensuremath{_{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@#1}}}}} 
  \usepackage{babel}
  \makeatother 

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
%%          Neudefinitionen         %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 

\usepackage{array} % Erlaubt mit v{} statt p{} Blocksatz in Tabellen abzuschalten
\newcommand{\PreserveBackslash}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}
%\usepackage[NewCommands]{ragged2e} % Better raggedleft formating
\newcolumntype{v}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash{\raggedright}\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}


%% Seitendefinition %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\usepackage[includeheadfoot]{geometry}             %   Normale Seitenränder
%\usepackage{a4wide}                                %   Kleinere Seitenränder = mehr Text pro Zeile.

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}  %   Selbstdefinierte Seitenränder
%\setheadsepline{1pt}[{\color[rgb]{0.75,0.75,0.75}}]    %   Graue Trennlinie bei Kopfzeile
%\setheadsepline{1pt}[{\color[rgb]{1,1,1}}]             %   Schwarze Trennlinie bei Kopfzeile

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}                              %   Alternativ Fancy Kopf- und Fußzeilen


%% Farbedefinitionen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{dunkelgrau}{rgb}{0.65,0.65,0.65}
\definecolor{hellgrau}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{weis}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{rot}{rgb}{1,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{gruen}{rgb}{0.9,1,0.9}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.4}
%\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{255,127,0}                           %   Eigene Farbdefinition RGB
%\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}                             %   Eigene Farbdefinition rgb 
%\colorlet{notgreen}{blue!50!yellow}                            %   Farben mischen mit xcolor


%% Zellendefinitionen für colortbl und Allgemein %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcolumntype{A}{>{\color{white}\columncolor{red}[.5\tabcolsep]\raggedright}p{2cm}}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\color{white}\columncolor{green}[0pt]\raggedright}p{2cm}}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}[0pt]}}

%Untenstehende Neudefinition ersetzt durch tabulary-Paket
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}l{#1}}        % zentrierte Spalten mit Breitenangabe 
%\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}l{#1}}       % rechtsbündige Spalten mit Breitenangabe 
%\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X{#1}}      % zentrierte Spalten mit Breitenangabe 


%% Eigene Definitionen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\halmos}{\quad\hfill\mbox{$\Box$}}                  %   Beweisendezeichen 
\def\bigdot{$\bullet$}                                          %   Dicker schwarzer Punkt 
\newcommand{\vektor}[1]{\left(\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right)} %   Vektoren 

%Minititel
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\minitit}[1]{
\begin{onehalfspace}
\emph{\textbf{#1}}
\end{onehalfspace}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Vorgaben %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\graphicspath{{./Bilder/}}                                  %Standardpfad für Bilder/Grafiken festlegen
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg,.png}


%% Literaturverzeichnis %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\bibliographystyle{./din1505/alphaabbrvdin}


\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,
style=alphabetic,                               % Zitierstil [Bur12, S. 4]
firstinits=true,                                % Vornamen im Literaturverzeichnis auf einen Buchstaben abkürzen
isbn=false,                                     % keine ISBN Nummern anzeigen
maxalphanames=1]                                % nur erster Autor in eckigen Klammern
{biblatex}  
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}             % bei mehreren Autoren kein + im Zitat bsp: [Jak+13]
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}% Doppelpunkt zwischen Autoren und Titel
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space} % Strichpunkt zwischen Autoren
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ al\adddot}}  % Verwendung von et al. statt u. a. im Literaturverzeichnis
\AtBeginBibliography{                           % Autorennamen in Kapitälchen nur im Verzeichnis, nicht im Text
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}  % Autorennamen in Kapitälchen
}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}          % Nachnahme zuerst: Nachname, V.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}                                                   % Titel kursiv und nicht in Anführungszeichen
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{journaltitle}{#1}
                                                % Zeitschriftentitel nicht kursiv
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%           % Definition für "article"
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{.\space In:\space}%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\space}
  \printfield{number}
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space S. \space}
  \printfield{pages}
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \finentry}  
  
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%            % eigene Kategorie "online" für Internetdokumente
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{.\space}%
  \printfield{url}%
  \setunit*{,\space abgerufen am\space}%
  \printfield{note}%                            % "note" nutzen für "URL last checked"
  \finentry}

%\nocite{*}                                     % Alle im Text unzitierten Einträge zitieren
%\addbibresource{Diss.bib}
\bibliography{BAMA.bib}

\defbibheading{quelle}{\chapter*{Literaturverzeichnis}}         % Mehrere Literaturverzeichnisse: Überschriften
\defbibheading{grundlagen}{\section*{Grundlagen und Recherche}}
\defbibheading{modelle}{\section*{Modellbildung}}
\defbibheading{prototyp}{\section*{Prototypenentwicklung}}
\defbibheading{fem}{\subsection*{FEM-Analyse des \textsc{Mute}-Batteriepacks}}
\defbibheading{sicherheit}{\subsection*{Sicherheitstests der im \textsc{Mute} verwendeten Zellen}}
\defbibheading{fmea}{\subsection*{FMEA-Analyse des Gesamtsystems}}
\defbibheading{kollegen}{}
\defbibheading{mpresse}{}
\defbibheading{epresse}{\section*{Ausgewählte Presseartikel zum Thema Elektromobilität}}
\defbibheading{webseite}{\section*{Internetquellen}}
\defbibheading{eigene}{\chapter*{Verzeichnis eigener Veröffentlichungen im Kontext Elektromobilität}}
\makeindex



%Deprecated
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,style=numeric,firstinits=true,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,style=alphabetic,firstinits=true,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex} % alphabetic: Zitierstil [Bur12, S. 4]; firstinits=true: Vornamen im Literaturverzeichnis auf einen Buchstaben abkürzen, Nur Ersten Author
```

Comment: The code as posted just produces the error `! Package babel Error: You haven't specified a language option.` not the error described in the question. Please edit the example so that it _reproduces the error_

Comment: if  `\include` fails but `\input` works, it is worth removing all `.aux` files (`\include` will generate aux files for each included file which you can delete).

Comment: If I comment out the `mcode` package (which isn't in standard distributions) the posted code runs without error.

Comment: please show the full error message from the log, including a line or two before the error message, that will show the context that generated the error.

Comment: Please give the people who gave you that template file the following links: [LaTeX-Vorlagen](http://niederberger.com.de/latex-vorlagen) and [Minimale Vorlage vs maximale Probleme](http://www.komascript.de/latexvorlage). I bet you don't need 90 % of those packages. Out of interest, are you using Matlab?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to answer?